# (Ubuntu) Tried to move my MongoDB database to an external drive and now it throws errors

Tags: mongodb

I can run mongodb fine from my internal drive but if I try to set the `--dbpath` to my external drive, I get the following error:

```
2017-10-17T17:12:36.091-0500 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=30644 port=27017 dbpath=/home/data/database 64-bit host=machine
2017-10-17T17:12:36.092-0500 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.12
2017-10-17T17:12:36.092-0500 [initandlisten] git version: d73c92b1c85703828b55c2916a5dd4ad46535f6a
2017-10-17T17:12:36.092-0500 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build5.ny.cbi.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2017-10-17T17:12:36.092-0500 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-10-17T17:12:36.092-0500 [initandlisten] options: { net: { port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/home/data/database" } }
2017-10-17T17:12:36.096-0500 [initandlisten] journal dir=/home/data/database/journal
2017-10-17T17:12:36.096-0500 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2017-10-17T17:12:36.096-0500 [initandlisten] LogFile::synchronousAppend failed with 8192 bytes unwritten out of 8192 bytes;  b=0x467a000 errno:5 Input/output error
2017-10-17T17:12:36.096-0500 [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 13515
2017-10-17T17:12:36.104-0500 [initandlisten] 0x121df81 0x11bd689 0x11a019d 0x11bdae8 0xa765bd 0xa76bb5 0xa76e55 0xa6a61a 0x76e726 0x76f53b 0x76fb85 0x76fe59 0x7f8636ba9830 0x766419 
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0x121df81]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x159) [0x11bd689]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0xcd) [0x11a019d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7LogFile17synchronousAppendEPKvm+0x1a8) [0x11bdae8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur20_preallocateIsFasterEv+0x13d) [0xa765bd]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur19preallocateIsFasterEv+0x25) [0xa76bb5]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur16preallocateFilesEv+0x145) [0xa76e55]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur7startupEv+0x5a) [0xa6a61a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14_initAndListenEi+0x456) [0x76e726]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x1b) [0x76f53b]
 mongod() [0x76fb85]
 mongod(main+0x9) [0x76fe59]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f8636ba9830]
 mongod() [0x766419]
2017-10-17T17:12:36.104-0500 [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure


2017-10-17T17:12:36.108-0500 [initandlisten] SEVERE: Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
Backtrace:0x121df81 0x121d35e 0x7f8636bbe4b0 0x7f8636bbe428 0x7f8636bc002a 0x11a020a 0x11bdae8 0xa765bd 0xa76bb5 0xa76e55 0xa6a61a 0x76e726 0x76f53b 0x76fb85 0x76fe59 0x7f8636ba9830 0x766419 
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0x121df81]
 mongod() [0x121d35e]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x354b0) [0x7f8636bbe4b0]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0x7f8636bbe428]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a) [0x7f8636bc002a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0x13a) [0x11a020a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7LogFile17synchronousAppendEPKvm+0x1a8) [0x11bdae8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur20_preallocateIsFasterEv+0x13d) [0xa765bd]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur19preallocateIsFasterEv+0x25) [0xa76bb5]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur16preallocateFilesEv+0x145) [0xa76e55]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo3dur7startupEv+0x5a) [0xa6a61a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14_initAndListenEi+0x456) [0x76e726]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x1b) [0x76f53b]
 mongod() [0x76fb85]
 mongod(main+0x9) [0x76fe59]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f8636ba9830]
 mongod() [0x766419]
```

It mentions a lot of system files and I once tried to mess with them when I tried to fix some Qt applications and bricked my system. So I'm hoping someone here knows anything about this?

My main internal drive was full and this database holds 500,000+ records of JSON (not private) so I can't store it on my internal drive since this 1 collection takes up 250+GB. Yeah it's a lot.

I have my 4TB drive that is storing all the data for my application. I tried to cp the folder into my external drive but when I try to run `mongod --dbpath /path/to/file` it throws this long error.

It works fine if I try to run it off a database on my internal drive. I changed permissions for my external drive and I read/write files to other folders on that drive all the time so I'm not sure why Mongodb doesn't want to do it.

I even tried to symlink the external drive's mounted location and then tried to run the mongo daemon with `--dbpath` pointed to the symlink which resides on my internal drive but it throws the same error.

Comment: What is file system on that external drive.. Hopefully not NTFS or FAT32... XFS or EXT4 would be "nice"...

Comment: The drive is formatted in NTFS. I originally used my mac to format the Western Digital drive. Is mongodb incompatible with NTFS file systems?

Comment: Mongo (somehow) don't like (in Linux) other mounts than "native". If you run mongod in virtualbox, you cannot use shared storage. I guess that, in this case, it cannot use that storage at "low level" and there can be problems to set ownership and rwx bits... mkfs.ext4 that drive, it probably will solve your problem.

Comment: Interesting. I'll go and try to format it into ext4. It was initially giving me problems formatting to ext4 which is why I initially formatted it on my mac since my linux wasn't recognizing the original exFAT format on it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If you're still here...I forgot the drive is actually in HFS+.  I assume the same problem still exists, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format your external drive to some "native" Linux FS.  EXT4 is good. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JJussi for the answer.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.  Had an external drive with `HFS+` format and MongoDB couldn't read/write data to that drive because of the file system.  I backed up the data, formatted as `ext4` and now I can run a MongoDB database from it.  Thanks!

Edit:  Not sure if it was entirely necessary, but I easily did it by formatting with Disk Utility on my Mac and then switching to my Linux computer and formatting with GParted.

Comment: Excelent! I added "Answer", so you can mark it "right". ;-)